# Bash script command "git add --all" throws error

Tags: git, macos, bash

I'm trying to run a bash script that I've used on every GIT project I've ever created. It runs an add all, then commits with a given message, then does a push to a mirror on Github. For some reason, I've had nothing but problems with this particular project. I've removed every single line of code in the bash script to test this first line, but still get the error. If I run the command by hand `git add --all`, it adds all files as you'd expect. If I run the `release.sh`, however, it throws a strange error. Any help would be appreciated!

Contents of `release.sh`:

```
git add --all
```

Error message on running the bash script:

```
$ bash release.sh
'rror: unknown option `all
usage: git add [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -v, --verbose         be verbose

    -i, --interactive     interactive picking
    -p, --patch           select hunks interactively
    -e, --edit            edit current diff and apply
    -f, --force           allow adding otherwise ignored files
    -u, --update          update tracked files
    -N, --intent-to-add   record only the fact that the path will be added later
    -A, --all             add changes from all tracked and untracked files
    --ignore-removal      ignore paths removed in the working tree (same as --no-all)
    --refresh             don't add, only refresh the index
    --ignore-errors       just skip files which cannot be added because of errors
    --ignore-missing      check if - even missing - files are ignored in dry run
```

edit: This happens with any GIT command I use in this bash script.

Comment: Can it be some hidden special char? What happens if you write your script again from an empty file?

Comment: You didn't copy the error message verbatim. Please do a more careful job.

Comment: I can show you a screenshot. I copied it word for word. It says `'rror: unknown options \`all`

Comment: yolenoyer - I recreated the file and it fixed the problem. Odd. I had copied it verbatim from my working copy.

Answer (score 1):

> I recreated the file and it fixed the problem. Odd. I had copied it
>   verbatim from my working copy.

The file has had lines ending with `CR`, evident by the closing `'` *appearing* at the start of the error message.